# Is it possible to specify the stage variable for api gateway in serverless yml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am using the value of the stage variable (`stageVariables.requestType`) in my code to filter out socket or HTTP requests. I know how to set the stage variables for the API gateway manually. But I want to know if is there any way to set the stage variable in the `serverless.yml` file.

```
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
   const type = event.stageVariables.requestType ;
   if( type === "API" ){
     return await apiExecuter();
   }
   if (type === "SOCKET" ){ 
      return await socketExecuter();
   }
}
```

I have tried with following but it is not working:

```
service: test-project

provider:
 name: aws
 runtime: nodejs18.x
 region: us-east-2
 variables:
   requestType: 'API'                    -------------> here

functions:
 testFunction:
   handler: index.handler
   events:
     - http:
         path: /{proxy+}
         method: ANY
```

Comment: Did you try with the plugin? https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-stage-variables

Comment: @Caldazar - No, I will try with this

Comment: We can set stage variables by using the above @Caldazar mentioned plugin. Tq